# How can I use Crystal in Python packages/extensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, crystal-lang

Is it possible to use [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org/) in Python3 packages/extensions?

Comment: I don't know if there are specific crystal bindings for Python. You _can_ make [arbitrary system calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) that could run Crystal programs.

A more important question may be: What specific task are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to use bindings to another faster system programming language. System calls are no option for me. Crystal, Rust and D are possible candidates.

Comment: I don't think crystal is "plumbed" to created shared libraries yet, maybe ask on the google group...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dl` has been deprecated in python3, look at `ctypes`.

It might be possible as highlighted here: https://github.com/hyronx/crystal-shared-lib

What this might look like in `python3`:

```
from ctypes import *

cdll.LoadLibrary("libcrystal-shared-lib.so")

crystal = CDLL("libcrystal-shared-lib.so") 

crystal.test(None)
```

**note**

I am not sure at the moment how the primitives convert from Python's `None` to C's None to Crystal's `Nil`, but nil returns a `0_u64`, so it's a hint, of some sort.

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types
- https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/391785249f66aaf5929b787b29810aeb4af0e1e8/src/nil.cr#L42

related posts:

- https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/921
- https://github.com/hyronx/crystal-shared-lib
- https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes